# How to pass only one repository SVN to SSL?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, svn

How to create a second virtual host for SVN repositories who are passed to SSL?

I passed only one SVN repository to SSL (not others) by using SSLRequireSSL:

   SSLRequireSSL
   (... snip all the SVN config ...)

Now, I have to create a second virtual host for ssl.

Version SVN server: 1.6.4 Great thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by 'pass'? Does http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache help?

Answer (score 3):

In my mind you have to do something like this:

1. Lets say you have two paths for your repositories:

/var/lib/svn-secure for the repos you want to work over ssl

```
<Directory /var/lib/svn-secure>
   SSLRequireSSL
   (... snip all the SVN config ...)
</Directory>
```

/var/lib/svn for the repos you do not care if they are over ssl

```
<Directory /var/lib/svn>
   (... snip all the SVN config ...)
</Directory>
```

then you create two virtual hosts, one over ssl and the other plain text. and put the locations in the respective ones, the SSLRequireSSL will force the access to the directory to be done over over ssl or will deny the access.

Be warned, I did this from the top of my head, there might be syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks, back later to vote your answer if I succeed to...